# ghc does not report non-exhaustive pattern matches when using the `no-code` flag

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching, typechecking

I tend to repeatedly typecheck my programs in a terminal whilst modifying them in my editor of choice in order to get real-time feedback. I typically run something akin to: `watch -d -n 1 "ghc -fno-code NoIncompletePM.hs"`.

Unfortunately the `no-code` flag which I use to avoid compiling again and again code I don't care about yet seems to be incompatible with the `warn-incomplete-patterns` one. E.g. with this program:

```
{-# OPTIONS  -Wall             #-}
module NoIncompletePM where

argh :: Bool -> Bool
argh True = True
```

I never get any warning that `argh` is missing a case for `False`. It is possible to get all of these warnings by removing the `no-code` flag *and* adding the `force-recomp` one (so that the warning is displayed *every single time* and not just the first time it's compiled) but I precisely want to avoid compiling this code...

I could not find anything in the manual describing these as being incompatible so I'm guessing that it's either an unexpected behaviour or I am doing something wrong. Any clues?

Comment: Minor points: 1) Polling with `watch` looks suboptimal when you are not modifying code. You could write your own tool which runs ghc only when the source changed: in such case you would preserve the old messages, making `force-recomp` unnecessary. 2) Emacs Flymake does exactly what you are trying to do (I don't know which flags it passes to ghc -- it might generate code after all). I'm pretty sure there are other editors as well with the same feature. 3) `no-code` affecting warnings looks indeed wrong, but I can't reproduce it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known ghc bug:

https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/8101

Note that if you pass the `-c` flag for one-shot mode, then you *do* get warnings. So that's a workaround for now.

Sadly, it appears (https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/10600) that ghc 8.0 may rebreak this working even in one-shot mode, at least for one more release cycle.

Comment: I have moved on to using `ghcid` but I am not completely satisfied with this solution either so I'm glad to know that there is a workaround. Thanks!